# CKEditor tamanho da fonte

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Estou usando [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) e gostaria de personalizar meu editor.
Ao ser aberto, por padrão ele já viria com fonte Arial tamanho 20 por exemplo.
Em [minhas pesquisas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396036/how-to-increase-the-font-size-of-the-ckeditor) (entre [várias outras](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83723/set-a-default-font-family-and-size-in-ckeditor), e [outras](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/How-do-you-set-default-font-and-default-font-size), e [outras](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.font_style), [etc](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable)...), encontrei formas de alterar a configuração para **TODOS** os editores *(ou criar uma gambi no arquivo de configuração para um específico)*, mas eu gostaria de fazer tal alteração apenas para um editor específico de uma maneira bonita com JQuery.
Tenho o seguinte:

```
 $("#MeuEditor").ckeditor({
      height: 350,

      // Isso não Funciona:
      font_defaultLabel: 'Arial',
      fontSize_defaultLabel : '20'
  });
```

Ninguém sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: procurei e tambem não encontrei, porém fiz de outra forma - criei um arquivo config.js e configurei a fonte e fonte-size apontando para um textarea, e criei outro config2.js contendo as configurações padrões. Funcionou. Obs: não é comum fazer isso, teste e veja.

Comment: Cara, nunca consegui estilizar somente um textarea. Sempre quando mudava um, tinha que mudar o outro também (se houvessem duas textareas na página). Por exemplo, se eu quisesse um textarea com uma quantidade de botões de formatação e outra texarea com outra quantidade, não conseguia.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro da pasta do CKEditor, possui um arquivo chamado contents.css, nesse arquivo pode-se alterar tipo de fonte, cor, tamanho, entre outras coisas do seu textarea.

O pior é que eu já tinha tentado estilizar as informações no textarea nesse arquivo, porém não conseguia ver as alterações que tinha feito por causa do histórico, foi quando tive a genuinidade de tentar em outro browser.

[Fonte](https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/484774-como-definir-fonte-da-tag-textarea-do-ckeditor/)